# Tiny slivers and overlaps, even when using snapping when digitizing

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, topology, slivers

I am in the process of creating several large shapefiles of administrative divisions in Europe. I digitized them using the snapping feature as well as the tracing feature. There are no visible overlaps or slivers on the shapefile, except when I zoom in to a stupidly large scale (something like 2000:1). Yet, when I run Check Topology and check for gaps and overlaps, I get thousands of errors highlighting these tiny slivers and overlaps. This is a bit of a problem, as it leaves behind these slivers as gaps in the polygon when I do operations such as merging polygons etc.

I have a couple of questions about this: How did these tiny slivers and overlaps form? How can I avoid creating them in the future?

I am running QGIS 3.16 Hannover and GRASS 7.8.5.
[image: Screenshot of the errors]

Comment: Slivers can form anywhere that vertices along a common boundary are not exactly coincident (number and location). You may be better off digitizing boundaries once, then assembling polygons from boundaries.

Comment: Thank you. Why are the vertices along the common boundary not coincident? I used the snapping feature, so surely each point should be in the exact place of the other?

Comment: Only if you generated points within the snapping distance. Extra vertices in long, nearly straight sections and along twisty curves are common.

Comment: It seems that even when I generate points within the snapping distance when drawing any kind of vertex at all the vertex that is created is never exactly coincident with vertex I am snapping to. Here is an example: https://imgur.com/a/8Pa3dPo

Comment: Lots of potential reasons there, but I'm not a QGISer, so I won't even speculate.

Comment: Ah no worries, thanks for your help anyway!